# Makefile error: nothing to be done

Tags: c++, makefile

I have this makefile in my proyect:
[Please look my folders organization too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX8fh.png)

When I run `make` in `/TallerMetalSlug` I get `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'`

I also run `cat -e -t -v Makefile` to see if tabs are OK and i get:

```
CXX = g++$
CXXFLAGS = -lpthread -pthread$
$
LIBRERIAS = socket.cpp$
$
CLIENTE = Cliente$
SERVIDOR = Servidor$
$
.PHONY: all clean$
$
all:cliente servidor$
$
cliente:$
^I$(CXX) $(CLIENTE)/$(CLIENTE).cpp $(LIBRERIAS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o (CLIENTE)$
$
servidor:$
^I$(CXX) $(SERVIDOR)/$(SERVIDOR).cpp $(LIBRERIAS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o (SERVIDOR)$
$
clean:$
^Irm -f $(CLIENTE)/$(CLIENTE) $(SERVIDOR)/$(SERVIDOR)$
$
```

Comment: What are all the `$`'s for?

Comment: try "make clean" followed by "make all"

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Read about `cat` flags. The point here is to show that it's not the trivial and common mistake of using spaces instead of tabs in a `makefile`.

Comment: @YehezkelB. Well, in this case it seems _TABs aren't OK_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why? There are tabs (`^I`) for all the commands. The `$`s are the way `cat` makes line-ending visible.

Comment: @robor78 make clean works but make all doesn't, I get the same message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it adding `cliente` and `servidor` to `.PHONY`

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -lpthread -pthread

LIBRERIAS = socket.cpp

CLIENTE = Cliente
SERVIDOR = Servidor

.PHONY: all clean cliente servidor

all: clean cliente servidor

cliente:
    $(CXX) $(CLIENTE)/$(CLIENTE).cpp $(CLIENTE)/$(LIBRERIAS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(CLIENTE)/$(CLIENTE)

servidor:
    $(CXX) $(SERVIDOR)/$(SERVIDOR).cpp $(SERVIDOR)/$(LIBRERIAS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(SERVIDOR)/$(SERVIDOR)

clean:
    rm -f $(CLIENTE)/$(CLIENTE) $(SERVIDOR)/$(SERVIDOR)
```

Comment: Seems like the change is more about adding `clean` to `all` target (which is not what you'd want to do generally).

Answer (score 1):

The cliente and servidor targets output to $(CLIENTE) and $(SERVIDOR) respectively.

But the clean target deletes from $(CLIENTE)/$(CLIENTE) and $(SERVIDOR)/$(SERVIDOR)

Judging by the screenshot, the output should be in the sub folders. So change the cliente and servidor targets as follows

```
cliente:
    $(CXX) $(CLIENTE)/$(CLIENTE).cpp $(LIBRERIAS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(CLIENTE)/$(CLIENTE)

servidor:
    $(CXX) $(SERVIDOR)/$(SERVIDOR).cpp $(LIBRERIAS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(SERVIDOR)/$(SERVIDOR)
```